# JQUERY make checkbox items disabled when user selects one item in particular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to make all other options be set to DISABLED as user clicks on NESSUNA:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="NESSUNA" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2"> NESSUNA </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="cereali con glutine" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2"> Cereali con glutine </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="crostacei" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Crostacei </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="latte e lattosio" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Latte e lattosio </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="lupini" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Lupini </label>
```

---

JQuery part (I was trying with first option):

```
 $(function() {
    enable_cb();
    $("input:checkbox[name='allergie2[]'][value='NESSUNA").click(enable_cb);
});

    function enable_cb() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input:checkbox[name='allergie2[]'][value='cereali con glutine']").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox[name='allergie2[]'][value='cereali con glutine']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: `input:checkbox[name='allergie2[cereali con glutine]']` this is an invalid selector. use `[name='allergie2'], [name='cereali'], [name='con'], [name='glutine']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you could put an `id` on the first checkbox along with a common class on the other to make selecting them easier. Then when the first checbox is changed you can enabled/disable the other ones by their class.

Also note that the `for` attribute on your `<label>` elements is incorrect. It should hold the `id` of the related checkbox, not it's `name`. Try this:

```js
$('#nessuna').change(function() {
  $('.checkbox').prop({
    checked: false,
    disabled: this.checked
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="NESSUNA" name="allergie2[]" id="nessuna">
<label for="nessuna"> NESSUNA </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="cereali con glutine" name="allergie2[]" class="checkbox" id="cereali">
<label for="cereali"> Cereali con glutine </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="crostacei" name="allergie2[]" class="checkbox" id="crostacei">
<label for="crostacei">Crostacei </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="latte e lattosio" name="allergie2[]" class="checkbox" id="latte">
<label for="latte">Latte e lattosio </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="lupini" name="allergie2[]" class="checkbox" id="lupini">
<label for="lupini">Lupini </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` to the `checkbox`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="NESSUNA" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2"> NESSUNA </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="disable-others" value="cereali con glutine" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2"> Cereali con glutine </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="crostacei" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Crostacei </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="latte e lattosio" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Latte e lattosio </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="lupini" name="allergie2[]">
<label for="allergie2">Lupini </label>
```

and add a handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(".disable-others").click(function() {
        var current = $(this);
        current.prop("checked") ? current.siblings("checkbox").attr("disabled", true) : current.siblings("checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```